# how to remove quick type in ios 8 without disabling autocorrection?

Tags: iphone, ios8, uitextview, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

I want to remove quick type from ios 8 keyboard .for removing quick type i tried this code but it also removed autocorrection functionality .can anyone tell me any alternate for this?

```
 self.txtCommentMessage.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```